Django error: "(Campo oculto TOTAL_FORMS) y (Campo oculto INITIAL_FORMS) son obligatorios"
Hola buenas estoy desarrollando una pagina en django donde un usuario rellena los datos de un sorteo en un formulario. Estos datos se guardan en una base de datos mysql. Parte de la funcionalidad de la pagina es que el usuario puede recuperar el formulario con los datos ya introducidos del sorteo para añadir mas, modificar alguno o relanzar el sorteo de nuevo sin necesidad de volver a introducir todos los datos
Ahora para ello tengo estos formularios que son los que estoy utilizando para recuperar el sorteo, añadir participantes, agregar datos del sorteo etc...
class SorteoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sorteo
        fields = ['organizador', 'fecha_celebracion', 'presupuesto']
    
class SorteoRecuperadorForm(forms.Form):
    sorteoRecuperador = forms.CharField(label='Codigo del sorteo', max_length=50, required=False)
    
class ParticipanteExclusionForm(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nombre'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    exclusiones = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=100, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Exclusiones'}))

ParticipanteExclusionFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteExclusionForm)
ParticipanteFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteForm)

El control de los datos de estos formularios tanto para volver a relanzar el sorteo como para recuperar los datos se hace desde este metodo desde el cual se comprueba que formulario es cual:
def recuperar_sorteo(request):
    sorteo_form = SorteoForm(request.POST or None)
    ParticipanteExclusionFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteExclusionForm, extra=0)
    participante_formset = ParticipanteExclusionFormSet(request.POST or None, prefix='participante')
    recuperador_form = SorteoRecuperadorForm(request.POST or None)
    
    sorteo = None
    participantes = None
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'recuperar_sorteo' in request.POST:
            if recuperador_form.is_valid():
                # Recuperamos el sorteo y los participantes
                sorteo = Sorteo.objects.filter(recuperarSorteo=recuperador_form.cleaned_data['sorteoRecuperador']).first()
                if sorteo:
                    participantes = sorteo.participantes.all()

        if 'realizar_sorteo' in request.POST:
            if sorteo_form.is_valid() and participante_formset.is_valid():
             #Logica para guardar el sorteo
    
    context = {
        'sorteo_form': sorteo_form,
        'participante_formset': participante_formset,
        'recuperador_form': recuperador_form,
        'sorteo': sorteo,
        'participantes': participantes,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'index/recuperar_sorteo.html', context)

Todo esto se gestiona en la siguiente template
<form method="post" onsubmit="validarFormulario()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ recuperador_form }}
    <button type="submit" name="recuperar_sorteo">Recuperar</button>
</form>

{% if sorteo %}
<form action="" method="post" class="formCompleto">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="formSorteo">
        <div>
            <label for="organizador">Nombre organizador</label>
            {{ sorteo_form.organizador }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="fecha_celebracion">Fecha celebracion</label>
            {{ sorteo_form.fecha_celebracion }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="presupuesto">Presupuesto</label>
            {{ sorteo_form.presupuesto }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="copyForm">PARTICIPANTES</h3>
    <div class="encabezados-participantes">
        <h4>Nombre</h4>
        <h4>Email</h4>
        <h4>Exclusiones</h4>
    </div>
    {{ participante_formset.management_form }}
    <div id='participante-form-list'>
        {% for form in participante_formset %}
        <div class='participante-form'>
            {{ participante_formset.as_p }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div id='empty-form-participante' class='hidden'>{{ participante_formset.empty_form.as_p }}</div>
    <div>
        <button class="botonesForm botonADD" id='add-more' type='button'>Agregar participante</button>
        <input class="botonesForm botonDONE" type="submit" value="Realizar sorteo" name="realizar_sorteo">
    </div>
</form>
{% endif %}

Con su javascript correspondiente:
<script>
    function validarFormulario() {
        var campo = document.getElementById('id_sorteoRecuperador').value;
        if (campo.trim() == '') {
            alert('Por favor, complete el campo');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /* Logica para cargar los datos en el formulario */
    function inicio() {
        document.getElementById("id_organizador").value = "{{ sorteo.organizador }}"
        document.getElementById("id_fecha_celebracion").value = "{{ sorteo.fecha_celebracion }}"
        document.getElementById("id_presupuesto").value = "{{ sorteo.presupuesto }}"
    };

    inicio()

    /*Logica completa para el formulario de realizar sorteo*/
    const addMoreBtn = document.getElementById('add-more');
    const totalNewFormsParticipante = document.getElementById('id_participante-TOTAL_FORMS');

    addMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', add_new_form);

    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) { addMoreBtn.click() } function add_new_form(event) {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } const currentParticipantes = document.getElementsByClassName('participante-form'); let
            currentFormCountParticpantes = currentParticipantes.length; const
                formCopyTarget = document.getElementById('participante-form-list'); const
                    copyEmptyFormELParticipante = document.getElementById('empty-form-participante').cloneNode(true);
        copyEmptyFormELParticipante.setAttribute('class', 'participante-form');
        copyEmptyFormELParticipante.setAttribute('id', `form-${currentFormCountParticpantes}`); const regex = new
            RegExp('__prefix__', 'g');
        copyEmptyFormELParticipante.innerHTML = copyEmptyFormELParticipante.innerHTML.replace(regex,
            currentFormCountParticpantes); totalNewFormsParticipante.setAttribute('value', currentFormCountParticpantes + 1);
        formCopyTarget.append(copyEmptyFormELParticipante);
    } </script>

Esto a la hora de ejecutarlo dentro del formulario me salta los errores:
(Campo oculto TOTAL_FORMS) *Este campo es obligatorio.
(Campo oculto INITIAL_FORMS) *Este campo es obligatorio.

Pruebas e hipotesis

Desactivar los if de la plantilla, esto elimina el error hasta que se introduce el código del sorteo que se va a recuperar
Dejar solo el formulario de los datos del sorteo y no recuperar los participantes/exluciones y el fallo no aparece
Comprobar si el los campos TOTAL_FORMS y INITIAL_FORMS existen y si se renderizan correctamente
En la plantilla donde el usuario introduce los datos del sorteo por primera vez no aparece el error
Quizá el fallo sea que haya 2 formularios en la misma vista, he probado a poner un boton de un nombre distinto y así poder controlarlo en la vista.

